# Insert Value With Different Type

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I wanted to insert a different value to the table from this code.

```
<tr>
    <td class="column">Problem Type</td>
        <td>:
            <select name="typeProb" id="typeProb" class="form-control">
                 <option value="-1">Select</option>
                        <cfloop query="listTyprProb">
                 <option value="#listTyprProb.code#">#listTyprProb.description#</option>
                        </cfloop>
            </select>
        </td>
</tr>
```

One field to insert the code selected,
Another one to insert the description selected.

How's the sql needed to be?

Comment: So what's the question here? Can you expand what you've written to include an actual question. Also include what you've done already by way of trying to answer the question.

Comment: @AdamCameron what's the sql i need to do?

Comment: You run an insert query.  If you don't know what that is, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.  Also, your question is odd.  You say you want to insert a different value to a table, but the choices are coming from query results.

Comment: @shasha, OK, so *update your question* to ask a coherent question, and "include what you've done already by way of trying to answer the question". What have you done so far? Do not reply in a comment, just get your question sorted out so it's fit for answering.

Comment: @shasha one point of a database is to reduce storing redundant data. why not query the database to get the description?

Answer (score -1):

I guess what you want to do is insert the user selected values into the database. Based on the selection, you want to insert the value into two fields. If this is not correct, please ignore. Otherwise read on.

First, change your option from this:

```
   <option value="#listTyprProb.code#">#listTyprProb.description#</option>
```

to

```
  <option value="#listTyprProb.code#|#listTyprProb.description#">
    #listTyprProb.description# 
 </option>
```

Next, in your sql use:

```
<cfquery name="somename" datasource="Your_DSN">
    insert into Your_Table (code,description) 
    values
    (
    <cfqueryparam value="#ListFirst(FORM.typeProb,'|')#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"/>
    , <cfqueryparam value="#ListLast(FORM.typeProb,'|')#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"/>
    ) 
</cfquery>
```

Comment: That will behave unexpectedly if the description contains a `|`. A more solid approach is to stick with a single value and use the "code" to do an `INSERT/SELECT` query.

Comment: Though I would first question *why* they want to de-normalize the data this way..

Comment: Why do we (the CF community) in nit-picking? Do we want OP to just copy & paste? Wouldn't user get to know if it fails with |, and can figure it out or post a follow up question? His approach is wrong. Agree. But he didn't asked for approach. He asked for a solution and any dev with fair bit of knowledge can customize it. I put efforts to understand what s/he is asking. Rather than answering or supplementing it with your knowledge you downvote it. Well that is much easier than trying to understand what a not-native English speaker trying to say/ask. Enough of rant .....

Comment: Why would you recommend code you know is flawed from the outset? (There are at least two easy ways to fix it. I already gave you one.) Instead of ranting, why not take the opportunity to fix it and improve the answer? *he didn't asked for approach.* So if the guy is about to do something that will light him on fire, we should not tell him because he did not ask? Come on ;-)

Comment: I disagree. Code is not "flawed from the outset". It has its limitations, otherwise every list function is flawed because it uses comma as normal separator. It is just that as a senior member you were expected to suggest it to accept it with a pinch of salt. The method (use the code to do an insert/select query) you suggested could be a v. good option but you might have found out by reading the question that OP is not even to minimum level to a CF dev yet. Peace.

Comment: Wrong. The expectation on S.O. is for people to use the feedback given by votes and comments to improve their answers. If you would rather complain about it, than acknowledge and fix it (after someone has already **given** you the answer) that is certainly your choice. The problem is not limitations of list functions. You are simply using the wrong one! If you read the docs, `ListRest` would avoid the issue with multiple delimiters. Though as I already said, insert/select is still a better option as it avoids delimiter issues and provides validation as well.

Comment: *OP is not even to minimum level to a CF dev yet* That completely contradicts what you said earlier, but whatever their experience level ... wouldn't you want to show someone the correct way to do things, rather than suggesting brittle code that may break?

Comment: @Leigh you have better suggestion?

Comment: @shasha - Review the comments. I suggested two options: insert/select and ListRest. But .. your table structure seems sub-optimal. It is possible there is a better approach. [As Matt asked earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645828/insert-value-with-different-type/24651037?noredirect=1#comment38216293_24645828), why are you duplicating the description? Duplication can cause data integrity issues.